# I have a class, how to I get it into listview effectively?

Tags: android, json, mobile

I have made a class called Listing:

```
public class Listing {
    @Key private int id;
    @Key private String name;
    @Key private float lastname;

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
public void setName( String name ) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastname;
}
public void setLastName( String lastname ) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
```

}

And I am able to create an array of Listings that I pull from a server and store it in a variable.

I can then basically call `variable[1].getLastName` and get all the values I need like that.

However, I am completely confused about putting this in listview. Can someone point me in the right direction? I found this page really helpful http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html, but I'm not really sure how to connect it to what I already have?

Any and all help is appreciated!

Here is currently how I have my set up. This is my adapter, which is mostly from the tutorial:

```
    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<String> objects) {
      super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
      for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
        mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
      }

    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
      String item = getItem(position);
      return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
      return true;
    }
    String[] values = new String[] {
            "1", "2"
    };
    //the stuff I've commented out in this next section give me nullpointer exception, where listinginfo is the varible I have saved my call to.
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
          .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      // thisListing = listinginfo[position];
      View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_cell, parent, false);
      TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstline);
      TextView smallerTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
      //String currentadd = listinginfo[position].getName();
      ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
      //textView.setText(currentadd);
      //smallerTextView.setText(listinginfo[position].getLastName);
      return rowView;
    }
}
```

I can call the listinginfo[position].getLastName in the same method where the request succeeds however.

I am also able to make the listview in the onCreate method, but that is only when I generate fake data right before it like this:

```
    //generate fake data for listview
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    String[] values = new String[] {
            "jon", "jim", "mary"
    };
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0;i < values.length;++i){
        list.add(values[i]);
    }
```

Comment: This is a good start and the research effort is commendable, however, what have you done in the way of trying to create the `ListView` according to what you learned in that tutorial? Do you have an `Activity` with a `ListView` or a `ListActivity`?

Comment: oh good point, give me a second to edit my post!

Comment: What's all this business with the HashMap? If an array of Listing objects has all the data you need just pass it in to the constructor of the adapter and use it in the getView as I described in my answer.

Comment: Please see my updated answer which should work for you to get started and mark as accepted please.

Comment: I thank you so much. I actually understand listviews a lot better now as well. Just a quick question, what is the constructor expecting as mylistings when you call it in the activity?

Comment: If you already have an array of listings do this: ListingsAdapter listingsAdapter = new ListingsAdapter(this, Arrays.asList(myListingsArray)); Alternatively, you could store the Listing objects in an ArrayList to begin with or modify the adapter to take an array. I think it's better to keep it as a list if you want to add stuff to the adapter later.

Comment: Well looking at the defintion of Arrays.asList() I think you want to start of with an ArrayList<Listing> to begin with because that method indicates that adding or removing from the List is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial you mentioned, take a look at Section 3.2. Instead of

```
String[] values;
```

in your adapter, you will have something like

```
Listing[] listings;
```

Then, in the getView() method of your adapter, you will fill in the appropriate values in the TextViews. Something like:

```
textView.setText(listings[position].getLastName());
```

Try this:

```
public class ListingsAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
List<Listing> listings;
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public ListingsAdapter(Context context, List<Listing> listings)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.listings = listings;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService
            (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_cell, parent, false);
    }

    TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstline);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);;

    Listing listing = listings.get(position);

    text1.setText(listing.getName());
    text2.setText(listing.getLastName());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listings.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

}
```

In your Activity do this:

```
final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
ListingsAdapter listingsAdapter = new ListingsAdapter(this, myListings);
listview.setAdapter(listingsAdapter);
```